# I have problem reset password in django . My error is 'availabe Apps' key error

Tags: python-3.x, django, reset-password

Firstly I call:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
```

After that I have set the url:

```
path('reset_password/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),name='reset_password'),
```

When I run the url the key error raised.

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/reset_password/
Django Version:     3.1
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    

'available_apps'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Syed Mithu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py, line 83, in __getitem__
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Syed Mithu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.3
Python Path:    

['F:\\12.05.2021\\Project\\Music_E-com',
 'C:\\Users\\Syed '
 'Mithu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Syed Mithu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Syed Mithu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Syed Mithu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\Syed '
 'Mithu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Syed '
 'Mithu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Syed '
 'Mithu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Syed '
 'Mithu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

Server time:    Thu, 20 May 2021 06:51:41 +0000
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the relevant code.

Comment: Could you search **all your** code for the word `available_apps`? What do you find?